# All vs Whole with singular nouns: Which should I choose?

Tags: quantifiers

Which should I choose when there's a singular countable noun?

```
e.G.:
```

> My whole youtube channel was made thinking about recording Snes gameplays.

> All my youtube channel was made thinking about recording Snes gameplays.

The Cambridge dictionary explains this subject [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/all-or-whole), but it isn't that clear to me.

I would be very grateful if someone could explain it to me. Thanks.

Comment: The part about 'single entities' applies here. If you did use _all_, it would have to be _all **of** my YouTube channel_.

Comment: Hmm.. I recognize your effort, but your answer doesn't help me much, ahaha. Sorry. What could be defined as a single entity? Are they always interchangeable when we use "all of"? Thank you and so sorry. ahaha.

Comment: Cambridge says _We use the whole or the whole of to refer to complete single things and events that are countable and defined._ I would call an individual YouTube channel a 'single thing', so I would say _My whole You Tube channel_ or _the whole of my YouTube channel._